# Using angular 4 as a part of existing web application

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs

Is this possible (and is this good idea ?) to use angular4 as a part of existing web application ? I can not rewrite whole application to angular. I need to develop a module with a lot of charts, tables (with real time data) and huge amount of repeatable components, so I am looking for some technology that I can use along with jQuery, underscore (and some other js libs) and let me doing extensible components, easy to use and easy to extend. Maybe can you propose some other solution, maybe react will be better or somethin else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say Angular would be a little heavy for this because it's a full fledged framework. React will definitely be a better fit. I've personally used React for small components on my existing pages. The only time I've used Angular is when the whole app is written in it.

Vue.js is also a good option.

Comment: I agree with you